# Creating an API for retrieving data from a MySQL Database as efficiently as possible

Tags: mysql, rest

I have an "architecture" question for a project I'm currently working on. I currently have a Python script that scrapes a website and then inserts the data into MySQL database. The DB has the following structure:

| address | price | date_created | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Address one, main street | £150,000 | 13/10/2022 | new data |
| Address one, main street | £140,000 | 16/10/2022 | update data |
| Address two, side road | £350,000 | 13/10/2022 | new data |

Whereby every price update has its own record. I'm going to create an API so that I can GET price information for a given address (for example: "Address one, main street ") which I would expect to then return 2 records and their relevant contents. I've read some conflicting information on this approach, such as a lack of a unique identifier being a problem or the API would be slow with poor performance. The DB currently has around 7000 records and whilst it is always growing, will never be into the millions for example.

Is the above approach short-sighted and likely to be inefficient/ unfeasible as the DB grows (possibly 100,000 rows) - or likely to perform poorly?

I'm really new to this so any advice on my approach would be really appreciated

Comment: If you have an index on the `address` column, performance should be fine.

Comment: How would adding a unique ID field help? How would the client know what ID to query for if they want to search for an address?

Comment: What is your specific question? This isn't a discussion forum, we can't brainstorm your API design with you.

Comment: Lack of unique identifiers doesn't make a database slow in itself, but it does make it harder to find specific rows. If you were to add tables that reference each other, then the lack of unique identifiers could potentially make it slow because searching for an identifier is a lot less intensive than searching for a specific string of text in a column because of indexing. You don't always need an identifier. And if you eventually do need one, it's never too late to add one.

Comment: At any rate, this question doesn't really seem on topic for this site. You may have better luck asking on the [Software Engineering Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/) which allows discussions about architecture.

Comment: Thanks for your replies so far. I guess my question is, is the above approach of the following basic database structure logical for an ever growing DB? (could reach 100,000 records) in next few yrs. Is there a concern over comparing text (input vs records) compared to having a numeric ID to search for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scraping involves multiple steps:

1. One (or several) processes, each reaching out to the other sites to download the pages.
2. Parse the page.
3. Clean up the data -- Remove '£' and commas from the price; rearrange the date to be yyyy/mm/dd format, etc.
4. `INSERT` into the database.  (Optionally, batch several rows into a single Insert.)

Step 1 is the slowest for elapsed time, even if you have multiple processes.

As for what the table schema should look like -- well, that depends on what the `SELECTs` will be.  You will need some `INDEXes` based on the queries.

The biggest hassle will be in step 3 -- "Main Street" = "Main St." = "Main St", etc.  You will need to come up with a canonical form for variations in the spelling, spacing, abbreviations, missing parts, etc.  Do not depend on the Select being able to handle such, though it may have to handle some of it.

With those tips, 100K rows should not be a problem.  (Unless you expect a million Selects per hour.)